# Back-off restarting failed container In Azure AKS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, linux-containers

Linux container pod, with docker images from Azure Container registry, keeps restarting with restartPolicy as Always. Pod description is as below.

```
kubectl describe pod example-pod

...

State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Thu, 11 Jun 2020 03:27:11 +0000
      Finished:     Thu, 11 Jun 2020 03:27:12 +0000
...
Back-off restarting failed container
```

This pod is created with secret to access ACR registry repository. 
  Reason is that pod completes execution successfully with exit code 0. However, It should keep listening at particular port number. Microsoft document link is at this URL [Container Group Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting) under header "Container continually exits and restarts"

**deployment-example.yml** file content is as below.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-deployment
  namespace: development
  labels:
    app: example
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: example
        image: contentocr.azurecr.io/example:latest
        #command: ["ping -t localhost"]
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - name: http-port
          containerPort: 3000
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regpass
      restartPolicy: Always
      nodeSelector:
        agent: linux
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example
  namespace: development
  labels:
    app: example
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http-port
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
  selector:
      app: example
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Output of *kubectl get events* is as below.

```
3m39s       Normal    Scheduled              pod/example-deployment-5dc964fcf8-gbm5t    Successfully assigned development/example-deployment-5dc964fcf8-gbm5t to aks-agentpool-18342716-vmss000000
2m6s        Normal    Pulling                pod/example-deployment-5dc964fcf8-gbm5t    Pulling image "contentocr.azurecr.io/example:latest"
2m5s        Normal    Pulled                 pod/example-deployment-5dc964fcf8-gbm5t    Successfully pulled image "contentocr.azurecr.io/example:latest"
2m5s        Normal    Created                pod/example-deployment-5dc964fcf8-gbm5t    Created container example
2m49s       Normal    Started                pod/example-deployment-5dc964fcf8-gbm5t    Started container example
2m20s       Warning   BackOff                pod/example-deployment-5dc964fcf8-gbm5t    Back-off restarting failed container
6m6s        Normal    SuccessfulCreate       replicaset/example-deployment-5dc964fcf8   Created pod: example-deployment-5dc964fcf8-2fdt5
3m39s       Normal    SuccessfulCreate       replicaset/example-deployment-5dc964fcf8   Created pod: example-deployment-5dc964fcf8-gbm5t
6m6s        Normal    ScalingReplicaSet      deployment/example-deployment              Scaled up replica set example-deployment-5dc964fcf8 to 1
3m39s       Normal    ScalingReplicaSet      deployment/example-deployment              Scaled up replica set example-deployment-5dc964fcf8 to 1
3m38s       Normal    EnsuringLoadBalancer   service/example                            Ensuring load balancer
3m34s       Normal    EnsuredLoadBalancer    service/example                            Ensured load balancer
```

Docker file entry point is like ENTRYPOINT *["npm", "start"]* with *CMD ["tail -f /dev/null/"]*

Comment: share output of kubectl get events

Comment: what code are you running inside the image (any script)?

Comment: I think the issue is about your image. You need to check if the image can run well locally.

Answer (score 0):

It runs locally. Implicitly, it assigns *CI="true"* flag. However, in docker-compose *stdin_open: true* or *tty: true* is to be set and in Kubernetes deployment file, ENV named variable *CI* is to be set up with value *"true"*.

Answer (score 0):

The below command solved my problem:-

```
az aks update -n aks-nks-k8s-cluster -g aks-nks-k8s-rg --attach-acr aksnksk8s
```

After executing the above command, below will be displayed:-

```
Add ROLE Propagation done [###############] 100.0000%
```

and then,
`Running..` followed by Response trail after some time.

Here,

```
aks-nks-k8s-cluster : Cluster name I have created and using
aks-nks-k8s-rg : Resource Group have created and using
aksnksk8s : Container Registries which I have created and using
```